# Use Service Principal to provision static Azure Files for Persistent Volume

Tags: azure, persistent-volumes, azure-files

Previously I was using the standard way of setting the PV on static azure files, i.e. create storage account and fileshare, create secret using the account name and secret of the storage account, then create the PV as below:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: elastic-storage
  labels:
    usage: elastic-storage
spec:
  capacity:
    storage: 5Gi
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteMany
  mountOptions:
    - dir_mode=0777
    - file_mode=0777
    - uid=1000
    - gid=1000
    - mfsymlinks
    - nobrl
  persistentVolumeReclaimPolicy: Retain
  azureFile:
    secretName: azure-secret
    shareName: elasticsearchfile2
    readOnly: false
```

I am now wondering whether I can use service principal instead of the azure secret using storage account name and key to access the azure files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's simple to understand. Azure supports the [RBAC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/overview) (role-based access) feature. And it can be used in the storage account. Just like two different users can read the same data in the database because they have enough permission the read. So if the service principal has enough permission for the storage account, then it also can access the storage account.

Comment: I understand that my service principal in theory can access the storage account. I am more concerned with the actual code to use in my pv.yaml file to use the service principal to access the azure files. Currently I have to use the azure secret which is created by the storage account name and key.

Comment: @Saligia Do you mean you don't know how to create the secret with the service principal?

Comment: I want to find an alternative to using a secret to authenticate and use the azure files. So I want to see if I can achieve that with service principal credentials.

Comment: @Saligia It seems you can't create the secret with the service principal for the volume. You see the options for the Azure file share are only `shareName` and `secretName`, no option for the storage account. If you use the service principle, then it can't point to the right storage account. It is designed by Kubernetes, you can feedback, but currently, it does not support.

Comment: I see, thanks. I have been looking for ways to use service principal instead of using secret, as using secret means having access to the whole storage account, but if we use service principal we can restrict access to only part of the storage account, i.e. azure files in this case.

I guess it isn't supported yet then, which is weird as I can do it with blob storage but not file share.

Comment: @Saligia Yeah, the storage account key has more permissions than need. But we can't do anything, the volume in k8s is only designed like this. Well, if you don't mind, please accept it if it's helpful to you.

Comment: Sure, thanks for the meaningful discussion